# How to get historical weather data (Temperature) on hourly basis for Chicago, IL

Tags: python, r, weather, weather-api

I need the historical weather data **(Temperature) on hourly basis for Chicago, IL (Zip code 60603)**

Basically i need it for the month of June and July 2017 either hourly or in 15 mins interval.

I have searched on NOAA, Weather underground etc. But haven't found anything relevant to my use case. Tried my hands on scraping using R and Python, but no luck.

Here is a snippet for the same

**R :**

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
url <- "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php"
response <- GET(url,query=list(zipCodeList="10001",
                           product="time-series",
                           begin=format(Sys.Date(),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                           Unit="e",
                           temp="temp",rh="rh",wspd="wspd"))
doc   <- content(response,type="text/xml", encoding = "UTF-8")   # XML document with the data
# extract the date-times
dates <- doc["//time-layout/start-valid-time"]
dates <- as.POSIXct(xmlSApply(dates,xmlValue),format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
# extract the actual data
data   <- doc["//parameters/*"]
data   <- sapply(data,function(d)removeChildren(d,kids=list("name")))
result <- do.call(data.frame,lapply(data,function(d)xmlSApply(d,xmlValue)))
colnames(result) <- sapply(data,xmlName)
# combine into a data frame
result <- data.frame(dates,result)
head(result)
```

**Error :**

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlSApply") : 
no applicable method for 'xmlSApply' applied to an object of class "list"
```

**Python :**

```
from pydap.client import open_url

# setup the connection
url = 'http://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/dods/NCEP_NARR_DAILY/197901/197901/narr-
a_221_197901dd_hh00_000'
modelconn = open_url(url)
tmp2m = modelconn['tmp2m']

# grab the data
lat_index = 200    # you could tie this to tmp2m.lat[:]
lon_index = 200    # you could tie this to tmp2m.lon[:]
print(tmp2m.array[:,lat_index,lon_index] )
```

**Error :**

```
 HTTPError: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

**Any other solution is appreciated either in R or Python or any related online dataset link**

Comment: First, asking for tutorials/software tools, etc. is off-topic on StackOverflow. However, you do make an attempt but do not explain what doesn't work, your input source, or desired output. And please post sample of downloaded XML to avoid we generous, time-limited volunteers from running the actual requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an R package `rwunderground`, but I've not had much success getting what I want out of it.  In all honesty, I'm not sure if that's the package, or if it is me.

Eventually, I broke down and wrote a quick diddy to get the daily weather history for personal weather stations.  You'll need to sign up for a Weather Underground API token (I'll leave that to you).  Then you can use the following:

```
library(rjson)

api_key <- "your_key_here"
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), as.Date("2017-07-31"), by = 1)
pws <- "KILCHICA403"

Weather <- vector("list", length = length(date))

for(i in seq_along(Weather)){
  url <- paste0("http://api.wunderground.com/api/", api_key,
                "/history_", format(date[i], format = "%Y%m%d"), "/q/pws:",
                pws, ".json")
  result <- rjson::fromJSON(paste0(readLines(url), collapse = " "))
  Weather[[i]] <- do.call("rbind", lapply(result[[2]][[3]], as.data.frame, 
                                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  Sys.sleep(6)
}

Weather <- do.call("rbind", Weather)
```

There's a call to `Sys.sleep`, which causes the loop to wait 6 seconds before going to the next iteration.  This is done because the free API only allows ten calls per minute (up to 500 per day).

Also, some days may not have data.  Remember that this connects to a personal weather station.  There could be any number of reasons that it stopped uploading data, including internet outages, power outages, or the owner turned off the link to Weather Underground.  If you can't get the data off of one station, try another nearby and fill in the gaps.

To get a weather station code, go to weatherunderground.com. Enter your desired zip code into the search bar

[image]

Click on the "Change" link

[image]

You can see the station code of the current station, and options for other stations nearby.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. But few queries, as I'm new to it. 1.This code works for each day? Since I need for each day for a period of 2 months (June and July) how do i go about it?
2. There are many parameters, but I need the temperature for that hour/day, so which parameter should i have refer?  Is it tempi?

Comment: And it is not taking for 1st-3rd of June, also which parameter to consider tempm or tempi?

Comment: `tempm` gives the temperature in Celsius.  `tempi` gives the temperature in Fahrenheit.  (`m` = metric, `i` = imperial).  See the edited code for a loop to collect multiple days.

Comment: Also note that since these are Personal Weather Stations (PWS), they may not always be connected to the internet and transmitting data.  Many of these are attached to residences. In order to get all of the data you need, you might have to piece together data from several stations.  It would be wise to save the data set and load it from memory, once you've put it all together.

Comment: And there seem to be a lot of missing values, in the sense for many timestamp the data is not captured. How to solve that issue?

Comment: what data aren't being captured? wind chill and wind direction, for example, will be missing if there wasn't any wind. Ultimatrly, we have no control over what each  station reports. if a station isn't reliable, we have go pick a different station. small price to pay for free dsta.

Comment: No, the timestamp is not captured. Oh okay

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a python solution for whoever comes by this question looking for one. This will (per the post) go through each day in June and July 2017 getting all observations for a given location. This does not restrict to 15 minute or hourly but does provide all data observed on the day. Additional parsing of observation time per observation is necessary but this is a start.

[WunderWeather](http://wunderweather.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

`pip install WunderWeather`
`pip install arrow`

```
import arrow # learn more: https://python.org/pypi/arrow
from WunderWeather import weather # learn more: https://python.org/pypi/WunderWeather

api_key = ''
extractor = weather.Extract(api_key)
zip = '02481'

begin_date = arrow.get("201706","YYYYMM")
end_date = arrow.get("201708","YYYYMM").shift(days=-1)
for date in arrow.Arrow.range('day',begin_date,end_date):
  # get date object for feature
  # http://wunderweather.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WunderWeather.html#WunderWeather.weather.Extract.date
  date_weather = extractor.date(zip,date.format('YYYYMMDD'))

  # use shortcut to get observations and data
  # http://wunderweather.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WunderWeather.html#WunderWeather.date.Observation
  for observation in date_weather.observations:
    print("Date:",observation.date_pretty)
    print("Temp:",observation.temp_f)
```

Comment: ,looks like wunderweather has stopped the free api's program.Any idea of apis that provide free keys?? I tried OpenWeather map but they dont have historical data in the free version.